# How can I give a nickname to an NPC?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

How can I give a nickname or items to an NPC in vanilla Minecraft?

Comment: I'm sorry, but your question is incomprehensible. Can you please try rephrasing it?

Comment: I think he's trying to ask how do you give NPC's nicknames and how do you change their loot... maybe...

Comment: I have voted to reopen this question, as I understand it quite well and am capable of answering it.

Comment: With the edit it's easy to understand and useful, I want to know how to arm villagers and name them so I can recognize them.

Answer (score 6):

Using commands (cheats) you can get a name above the villager doing the following:

1. Get a Villager Spawn Egg (`/gamemode 1` and locate to the Miscellaneous section.)
2. Rename the spawn egg using an anvil and some experience.

[image: Naming the Egg]

Now just spawn the villager using the egg.

[image: Spawned Villager]

You'll only see the name when you look at the mob.

Now if you don't get the Villager you want, just keep trying until you get the villager you want, while killing the extras off.

[image: I kill them with Lava. Mwahaha]

If you wait until 1.6, you can do this without cheating by using the [Name Tag](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Name_Tag) for other creatures other than the villager.  They can be crafted and by using an Anvil, you can rename the tag.  Then find a mob and build-click on it.  Now you have a name above the mob.  The downside is you cannot name villagers with this item, however that appears to be a snapshot bug (reported as a bug [#MC-14525 on Mojira](https://mojang.atlassian.net/browse/MC-14525)).

To answer the other part of your question, you can't give villagers any items, you can only trade with them.

Comment: According to the wiki, Villagers (and the ender dragon) are exceptions and cannot be named with name tags.

Comment: I did not know that.  I'll edit it now.

Comment: @musicwithoutpaper Yep, fixing now

Answer (score 2):

## Using MCEdit

You can give a nameplate to mobs by using Sethbling's [ChangeMobs](http://sethbling.com/downloads/mcedit-filters/changemobs/) filter: select a mob, type the desired name into `Name` and select `Show Name`.

You can give custom drops to mobs by using Sethbling's [CreateGearedMobs](http://sethbling.com/downloads/mcedit-filters/changemobs/) filter: put items that you want the mob to drop in a chest, run the filter on the chest and select which mob you would like.